# How to read Shape file and store details in postgresql using c# code

Tags: c#, shapefile

I have SHP files I want to create tool in c# to read SHP file and and insert correct details in postgresql database.

Also is there any way to reproject it using C# tool.

Comment: The SHP files you are talking about - are they related to arcgis? i.e., do they contain geographical data? If yes, then please take a lok at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50541/reading-shapefile-using-c

Comment: They will containg longitude, latitude, block_lot and other informatin related to apartments